# SSL key file and SSL cert file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new to Ruby and I need to find where is my ssl key file and ssl cert file to put on my Ruby app.

I've to tried generate cert file via https://whatsmychaincert.com/ which can generate .crt file extention. but how about my ssl key file which is the file using .key extention

My web project is https://vendorpedia.co.id.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "putting (a certificate) on your Ruby app"? What web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to enable/renew SSL certs for your website.
You need CA certified certs(and not self-signed) for that. Use sites like `letsencrypt.com` or check with your domain name provider.